# using variable for date range in a query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a query using a variable for my start and end dates.

```
Declare @startshiptransdate as datetime
Declare @endshiptransdate as datetime

SET @StartShipTransDate =  ISNULL(@StartShipTransDate, '08/30/2015')
SET @EndShipTransDate = ISNULL(@EndShipTransDate, '09/05/2015')

    (convert(date,co_ship.ship_date,101)  >= @StartShipTransDate
    AND convert(date,co_ship.ship_date, 101) <= @EndShipTransDate)
```

When I run this I come up about 200 records short of what I should have.

But, if I were to run it like this:

```
    (convert(date, co_ship.ship_date, 101)  >= '08/30/2015'
    AND convert(date, co_ship.ship_date, 101) <= '09/05/2015')
```

I get the correct number of records. I am sure it is something simple.

Comment: Can you please paste the entire query? You're leaving parts out which makes it difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: When you declare your variables as dates and not datetimes, do you get the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

It was requested that I post the rest of the query:

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare @startshiptransdate as datetime
    Declare @endshiptransdate as datetime


    SET @StartShipTransDate =  IsNull(@StartShipTransDate, '08/30/2015')
    SET @EndShipTransDate = ISNULL(@EndShipTransDate, '09/05/2015')
    select  
        'O' as rectype,
        ordercust.name as name,
        ordercust.city as city,
        ordercust.state as state,
        ordercust.zip as zip,
        co.cust_num as custnum,
        shipcust.city As shipcity,
        shipcust.state AS shipstate,
        convert(varchar(10),co_ship.ship_date,101)as ShipDate,
        item.item, 
        item.description, 
        co_ship.qty_shipped as Qtyshipped,
        co_ship.cost as Cost,
        co_ship.price AS price,
        co_ship.co_line as OLN

    from
        co_ship
            INNER JOIN coitem ON co_ship.co_num = coitem.co_num 
                    AND co_ship.co_line = coitem.co_line
                    AND co_ship.co_release = coitem.co_release
            INNER JOIN co ON co_ship.co_num = co.co_num
            INNER JOIN custaddr shipcust ON co.cust_num = shipcust.cust_num 
                    AND shipcust.cust_seq = co.cust_seq 
            Inner Join custaddr ordercust ON co.cust_num = ordercust.cust_num 
                    AND ordercust.cust_seq = 0 
            INNER JOIN customer ON customer.cust_num = co.cust_num 
                    AND customer.cust_seq = co.cust_seq
            INNER JOIN item ON item.item = coitem.item
    WHERE
        (convert(date,co_ship.ship_date,101)  >= @StartShipTransDate 
                AND convert(date,co_ship.ship_date, 101) <= @EndShipTransDate)
```